# Chrome extension scripting.executescript() running twice

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

```js
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
  if (changeInfo.status === 'complete') {
    if (tab.url.match('example1') || tab.url.match('example2') || tab.url.match('example3')) {
      id = tabId
      chrome.scripting.executeScript({
          target: {
            tabId: tabId
          },
          func: CO2_infopull,
          args: [tabId, username, userID]
        },
        function(results) {
          console.log(results);
        }
      );
    }
  }
});
```

`executescript` is running twice cause the callback `console.log` is logging twice.

The above code is a piece of my service worker where this listener is added and it checks when the info status is complete it matches the URL of the tab and then executes the script.

The problem is that this is running twice for some reason. If I add a breakpoint before `executescript` when that breakpoint is hit, the console already shows this log being ran once already and if I continue the execution then second log shows up.

I've tried making it `async` but nothing seems to be working. Any guidance would be much appreciated as I am not a veteran in JS.

Comment: You need to provide more information. I re-created this on my side using the code you have showing and mine only runs the console log once.

Comment: Does it reproduce even if no breakpoints are set?

Comment: yes it runs twice even if no break point are present

Comment: thats the problem it used to work absolutely fine till i switched my laptop

Comment: this instance of code is completely isolated in the background script, meaning this listener is added once the background script is loaded and thats it and called only when the url matches but for some reason the code is running twice. am thinking it has something to do with the signal R script running its ping program at the same time, i have imported signalR script in the background script using import()

Comment: a little update its not just the execute script thats running twice its everything inside the listener is running twice

Comment: Even I'm facing the same issue, have you found any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add allFrames: false to target like this
{
tabId: tabId,
allFrames: false
}